# Sticky Navigation after Scrolling position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the following website i have a navigation bar.
http://bit.do/bVXAs

I use this css code for the navigation:

```
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
background: #302f2f; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #302f2f 0%, #000000 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #302f2f 0%,#000000 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #302f2f 0%,#000000 100%); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#302f2f', 
endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
box-shadow: 0px 7px 31px -5px #000;
border-bottom: 15px solid #ff9500;s
```

An i use a Javascript Code for the position fixed:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('#navigationsleiste').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
}
}
```

Now when i scroll the Navigation Bar have a space to the top of the browser window. But i dont want that space/gap. Know anyone why i have that gap/space?

Comment: Because you have to wait for the window scroll top to match the navigation scroll top. That way there shouldn't be a gap.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to 'Why the gap' has been answered in the comments I believe.

More generally, on how to fix the issue:

CSS has a `position` property that's very suited for your sticky menu: `position: fixed`. When the menu is scrolled outside of view, you change its position to fixed. Once it's back at its original location, you remove your fixed positioning.

You want to do as little as possible in a method that is executed on scroll, since it is triggered very often. Once there's too much code execution on a scroll, you loose your smooth 60fps framerate.

So what you could do is:

- Make sure you always know how far the top of your sticky menu is away from the top of your window
- On scroll, check if this point has been reached
- Add or remove a class to your menu accordingly

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $doc = $(document);
  var $menu = $("nav");
  var menuTop = 0;

  var setMenuTop = function() {
    menuTop = $menu.offset().top;
  }

  $(window).resize(setMenuTop);

  $doc.scroll(function() {
    $menu.toggleClass("is-fixed", ($doc.scrollTop() > menuTop));
  });

  setMenuTop();
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  height: 160px;
  background: orange;
}
nav {
  heigth: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  will-change: transform;
}
nav.is-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  top: 0;
}

.is-fixed + article {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>header</header>
<nav>menu</nav>
<article>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nulla enim placeat? Iure modi quasi facere provident, quidem ducimus impedit nulla harum sunt corrupti. Rem velit architecto omnis molestias, repellat.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thats a great Example and very useful. Thank you for this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead $(window) set it better on $(document):
$('#navigationsleiste').css('top', $(document).scrollTop());